# org-babel evaluation of code block always creates new window

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Running org-ctrl-c-ctrl-c to evaluate a src block in an org file behaves strangely with windows. With a single window in the frame, it spawns a new window looking at the same buffer in a split and moves focus into the new window. When I have two or more windows open, eval-ing still moves focus to the furthest (last created) window.

What could be causing this, or how should I troubleshoot it?

Env info:

GNU Emacs 25.0.50.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0, NS appkit-1404.00 Version 10.11 (Build 15A282)) of 2015-09-27

Org-mode version 8.3.2 (8.3.2-10-g00dacd-elpaplus)

This behaviour occurs with no other config on emacs -Q and loading only org-mode.

Comment: Does it happen with every language, or just one / some?

Comment: It seems to be specific to scheme. Tried it with python, and that behaves normally.

Comment: When I try to execute Scheme source block in Org I see it switching into Geiser buffer and then back. Maybe something in this mechanism is broken... Are you using Geiser too?

Comment: Yes, I'm using geiser to interpret scheme.

Comment: Well, I don't have a good answer, but I'd try to instrument `org-babel-execute:scheme` and see when it launches this extra window.

Comment: Also, take a look at `geiser-repl-use-other-window`, just stumbled into it by chance, it sounds like it could be related.

Comment: @wvxvw this geiser-repl-use-other-window set to nil did the trick. Thanks.